# removing a specific word from a file extension using a windows batch file

Tags: batch-file

I need some help with batch scripting. I need to remove a specific word from a file extension using a windows batch script. Etc

```
Error_test_qif,
Error_test2_qif,
Test3_error_qif,
```

I need to get the "error" string removed from the file name to look like below

```
Error_test_qif to test_qif,
Error_test2_qif to test2_qif,
Test3_error_qif to Test3_qif,
```

I tried using the `ren*` command but it only works with bulk renaming from one file extension to another. Help would be appreciated

Comment: "removing a specific word from a file extension" - do you mean changing the name of the files?

Comment: Yup basically changing the name of the files etc

Comment: Error_test_qif to test_qif, Error_test2_qif to test2_qif, Test3_error_qif to Test3_qif, if you notice all the "error" string should dissappear after the script runs

Comment: Is the extension `.qif` or is there no extension and you're just using `_qif` at the end of the file name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can probably be simplified, but you get the idea:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in (*_error*) do (
  set "name=%%F"
  ren "!name!" "!name:_error=!"
)
for %%F in (*error_*) do (
  set "name=%%F"
  ren "!name!" "!name:error_=!"
)
```

save as .bat or .cmd and run in same directory as your files.

---

(original posted code rolled back - addendum below retained)

Much as I am loath to edit an answer, sadly the edited answer now presented is an adaption and will generate an error report for files named "...error..." which the original did not do.

Here's an adaption of the original post: (press the Edited datetime link below the response text for history)

```dos
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in (*_error* *error_*) do (
  set "name=%%F"
  SET "name=!name:_error=!"
  ren "%%F" "!name:error_=!"
)
```

I believe this is the best editing result to represent the responses.

Now we have a change to the specification. The filenames posted were not filenames as assumed but extensions only. This should be fixed like this:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for %%F in (*.*_error* *.*error_*) do (
  set "ext=%%~xF"
  SET "ext=!ext:_error=!"
  ren "%%F" "%%~nF!ext:error_=!"
)
```

Comment: @Magoo, My original answer was correct, and the solution should have worked. Someone edited it and then was down voted by one of the many people on this site that suffer from Dunning–Kruger effect. At the same time it doesn't give me much incentive to come back and participate either. I don't have Windows, nor do I want to; and what you're referring to about `...error...` doesn't tell me anything, — ah well, take care buddy, cheers!

Comment: Hey I'L'I, thanks for your help. I might require one more assistance from you. Isit possibe to retain the words before the file extension. So basically your code changes the word "error" in the file name.  Lets say error_test.error_parse2_qif. The code removes all the error but I want it to leave "error_test" alone and only change whatever error that appears after the "."

Comment: @l'L'l - the expression, I believe is "Illegitimis non carborundum." Yes - your original worked, on the problem as it was understood at the time. No doubt. I had to check that `for/f` would work with multiple filespecs and the gymnastics had to be massaged to cooperate. Would work the original way, you metioned "simplified" - yes, but not much and debatable. By then, cavalier changes had been made that didn't work as well, since at least one attempted rename would fail - CMD didn't complain as much as I'd anticipated it would, but it still complained, which wouldn't happen with your code.

Comment: @echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for %%F in (*.*_error* *.*error_*) do (
  set "ext=%%~xF"
  SET "ext=!ext:_error=!"
  ren "%%F" "%%~nF!ext:error_=!"
)  -----> with this code can I know how to add a statement to check for a specific folder.so basically this batch file will be it lets say folder x. I want it to execute files in folder y, but I need to check if folder y exists do the rename task if not throw a exception and exit(dont do any action).can it be added to the for loop?

Comment: @user1270779, you should be able to do something such as `set FOLDER_Y=C:\path to folder_y`... `if EXIST "%FOLDER_Y" ( your code from above ) else ( EXIT )`. <- include the `(` `)` — You might want to confirm with Magoo if that is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Hi magoo could you please help me out here

Answer (score 0):

This works for you ...

```
@echo off 
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "word=Error_"
IF "%word%"=="" GOTO :EOF
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /a-d /b "*%word%*.qif"') DO (
SET "fname=%%~na"
SET "fname=!fname:%word%=!"
IF NOT "!fname!"=="" REN "%%~a" "!fname!%%~xa"
```

)

Comment: I think he wants to remove the `error` text from filename, not the first three letters of every file.

Comment: try this on your system..its doing the same..! :)

Comment: I did. it removed the first three letters of every filename! o_O

Comment: and what was the full file name with extension you used ?

Comment: as per my EDIT..now please try again.

Comment: `ren "%fname%" "%fname:~3%"` will just remove the first three characters from the filename.

Comment: @unclemeat..ohh my fault..i was under impression that `Error`is always a starting word of every file..EDITED..! :)

Comment: Hi all the code from I'L'I worked exactly like how I wanted. So basically it is removing the word " error" from the file name.  So etc .error_parse2_qif --> parse2_qif. File name itself should be parse2_qif. Thanks alot to everyone for helping me out and a huge thanks to I'L'I. Let me do some testing on the code